# First Activity for apply Terms and Conditions

Tags: android

I want to build Terms and Conditions dialog display on a "startActivity". If the user clicked on the Accept button or clicked on a Checkbox, it start the app with MainActivity. But later, on second/third etc. start, i will skip the "startActivity", i will run the app direkt with the MainActivity. (if the user clicked earlier on the Accept button). How can this be solved?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences to store and access the user's response. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
    getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String res=sharedPref.getString("UserResponse","NONE");
    if(res.equals("Acccept")){
     //goto main activity here
    }

    //get user response into String response
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("UserResponse", response);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
I have Firebase in the app. And how can i disable the Firebase from Activity? If Sharedpreference result is false (its a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

1. Make sure your main activity is the one system starts

   ```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   ```
2. In your Main activity check if user has already accepted terms or no. If no, drive him to TnC activity.

Obviously state of TnC acceptance must be stored somewhere (preferences, room, firebase etc).